# Why is episode 6 so short in the OA season 1?

Tags: the-oa

I have just watched the first season of the OA and the length of the episodes feel weird :

episode 1 : 71 min
episode 2 : 58 min
episode 3 : 60 min
episode 4 : 64 min
episode 5 : 61 min
**episode 6 : 31 min**
episode 7 : 41 min
episode 8 : 50 min

Episode 6 is not even half of episode 1. It seems very unusual to make such variations in the episodes length, is there any explanation ? has a part of the episode been removed ?

The three last episodes could have been 2 one hour episodes (122 minutes), so why has it been cut like this ?

Comment: I remember seeing a good answer about Netflix being able to be flexible about show runtimes... trying to find it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question has been asked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheOA/comments/5k3td3/why_was_episode_6_so_short_spoilers_for_episode_6/) and here are a couple answers:

> Stylisation, not being bound to commercialism (adverts in most TV shows) or >the brainwashed expectation we have for formulaic structure and conformity. By not being bound to these, **they are able to tell the story like a novel through chapters of differing lengths.**

-

> **Comment from the co-creator**:
>
> Batmanglij: **We wanted to take what we love about a novel and the novelistic experience** and put it on the long-format series experience — not having all the characters in the first hour, **not having all the chapters be the same length.** Could you imagine if the chapters of a book were all the same length? It would be funny. So we thought to ourselves about those constraints.

And here's a link to [the co creator interview](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/oa-creators-netflix-series-season-2-959020)